# Different behavior of if else statement and if_else

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to create a function which converts the data type of a data frame to `factor` if the column is of type `char` otherwise I am not changing anything. But the problem here is that I am able to do the same with `if else` statement but not using the `if_else` statement 
here is the code for the same
Note - I am using the `titanic` data set

```
changetype = function(x)
  if(class(x) == "character") as.factor(x) else x
changetype2 = function(x)
  if_else(is.character(x),as.factor(x),x)
result1  = sapply(Train$Embarked, changetype)
result2  = sapply(Train$Embarked, changetype2)
```

`result1` is working fine whereas `result2` give me an error

```
Error: `false` has type 'character' not 'integer'
```

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: which package `if_else` comes from?

Comment: Could be the fact that `if_else` checks the type of your variables as well. Try `?if_else` to read a bit more.

Comment: from `?dplyr::if_else` : `Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks that true and false are the same type`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper can you please elaborate more

Answer (score 7):

`dplyr::if_else` is specifically written to force you to have the same type in your `true` and `false` arguments.

From: `?dplyr::if_else` :

> Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks
>   that true and false are the same type.

In your case `x` is character, so in the statement `if_else(is.character(x),as.factor(x),x)` , the `true` parameter will be `factor` (type `integer`) , and the `false` parameter will be `character`. `if_else` doesn't like that and thus returns:

> Error: `false` has type 'character' not 'integer'

Also, `dplyr::if_else` and `base::ifelse` are intended to be used with vectors, so in your case they're not good choices. With a regular `if` `else` call only the right condition will be evaluated, `if_else` and `ifelse` evaluate both.

Comment: Thanks a lot @moody