# ifelse() and if else given different results in dplyr mutate() for a time variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Let assume a data.frame like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID Date Condition
                1 2015/01/01  Yes
                1 2015/01/10  No        
                1 2015/01/15  Yes
                2 2015/02/10  No                                   
                2 2015/03/08  No
                3 2015/01/01  No                                     
                3 2015/04/01  Yes
                3 2015/04/10  No
                3 2015/04/01  Yes
                3 2015/04/10  No", header = TRUE)
```

I want to compute the number of days between a given date and the first date for every ID separately. Now, for every ID where the condition is always "No", I want to assign NA in the column with results.

This is my code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Temp = Date - first(Date),
         Res1 = ifelse(all(Condition == "No"), NA, Temp),
         Res2 = if(all(Condition == "No")) NA else Temp)
```

Results:

```
      ID Date       Condition Temp    Res1 Res2  
   <int> <date>     <fct>     <time> <dbl> <time>
 1     1 2015-01-01 Yes       0         0. 0     
 2     1 2015-01-10 No        9         0. 9     
 3     1 2015-01-15 Yes       14        0. 14    
 4     2 2015-02-10 No        0        NA  <NA>  
 5     2 2015-03-08 No        26       NA  <NA>  
 6     3 2015-01-01 No        0         0. 0     
 7     3 2015-04-01 Yes       90        0. 90    
 8     3 2015-04-10 No        99        0. 99    
 9     3 2015-04-01 Yes       90        0. 90    
10     3 2015-04-10 No        99        0. 99
```

My question is, what is the reason for ifelse() giving wrong results, while if else giving the desired results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/q/22433704 and related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50525719

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, you do not understand `ifelse`. It is fundamentally different from `if` and `else`. The documentation clearly says "`ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test`" which is a vector of length one in your example. `mutate` then recycles this.

Here is a simple example:

```
all(c(TRUE, TRUE))
#[1] TRUE
ifelse(all(c(TRUE, TRUE)), 1:2, 3:4) #test is vector of length 1
#[1] 1
ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1:2, 3:4) #test is vector of length 2
#[1] 1 4
```

I'd encourage you to study the source code of the `ifelse` function, which should make it obvious why it behaves like this.

Comment: @Roland thank you for explanation. I'm still learning the more theoretical aspects of R.

Comment: And the stricter `dplyr::if_else` would give an error when `yes` or `no` are not of the length of `test`: `dplyr::if_else(all(c(TRUE, TRUE)), 1:2, 3:4)`