# Writing other columns when matching a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I would like to create a new column, document it only when it matches a specific condition (here  `x > 2` ) and then **directly** overwrite another existing column (here `auxiliary`) for these rows where the condition (`x > 2`) returned TRUE.

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, auxiliary = NA)


# A tibble: 5 x 3
  x     y auxiliary
<int> <dbl> <lgl>    
1      1     NA       
2      2     NA       
3      3     NA       
4      4     NA       
5      5     NA
```

I can do this successfully in two different calls within `mutate()` :

```
df %>% 
    mutate(result = if_else(condition = x > 2,
                      true = x+y,
                      false = NA_real_),
     auxiliary = if_else(condition = x > 2,
                         true = "Calculation done", 
                         false = NA_character_))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  x     y auxiliary        result
<int> <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
1     1      NA                   NA
2     2      NA                   NA
3     3      Calculation done      6
4     4      Calculation done      8
5     5      Calculation done      10
```

But there's some code repetition (`condition = x > 2`) which, in more complex cases, makes reading the code very uneasy and prone to errors, especially when there are multiple conditions.

Is there a way to simplify the code above by not repeating the condition ? :

- Create new variable (`mutate()`)
- Document only if condition is matched (`if_else` or `case_when()`)
- Write another column's value only if the row's condition is matched. (**I'm stuck here**)

Something that would look like this :

```
df %>% 
   mutate(result = case_when(
            x > 2 ~ x + y & auxiliary == "Calculation done", # we'd add the column reference here...
            TRUE ~ NA_real & auxiliary = NA_character_))
```

Many thanks ! Any solution from the tidyverse would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the result of the condition in a column and use that to avoid evaluating the same condition again and again.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

df %>% 
  mutate(condition = x > 2,
         result = if_else(condition,
                          true = x+y,
                          false = NA_integer_),
         auxiliary = if_else(condition,
                             true = "Calculation done", 
                             false = NA_character_))

#      x     y condition result auxiliary       
#  <int> <int> <lgl>      <int> <chr>           
#1     1     1 FALSE         NA NA              
#2     2     2 FALSE         NA NA              
#3     3     3 TRUE           6 Calculation done
#4     4     4 TRUE           8 Calculation done
#5     5     5 TRUE          10 Calculation done
```

Comment: This looks like a good compromise. I will wait a bit to see if there are other solutions before validating this one which is similar to @JKupzig below

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving the condition which should be used multiple times as string and then using the string as variable in the code, e.g.:

```
condition <- "x>2"
df %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(eval(parse(text=condition)),
                          x+y,
                          NA),
         auxiliary = ifelse(eval(parse(text=condition)),
                             "Calculation done", 
                             NA))
```

Note, that I am using base ifelse statement, to avoid the restriction that I have to use the same type in the column ("dplyr::if_else is specifically written to force you to have the same type in your true and false arguments."). See further information on that e.g. [Different behavior of if else statement and if_else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525719/different-behavior-of-if-else-statement-and-if-else).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve the kind of abstraction you would like to have, but it does require more set-ups. `mutate` is actually more flexible than you think it is. You can pass a script to it. Suppose you write something like `A %>% mutate({...})`. If the script `{...}` returns a dataframe, then its columns will be created directly in `A` or replace the existing columns in `A` if they share the same names. So you can do

```
df %>% mutate({
  cond <- x > 2
  out <- tibble(.rows = n())
  mapply(
    \(var, true, false) out[[var]] <<- if_else(cond, true, false), 
    var = c("result", "auxiliary"), 
    true = list(x + y, "Calculation done"), 
    false = list(NA_integer_, NA_character_)
  )
  out
})
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
      x     y auxiliary        result
  <int> <int> <chr>             <int>
1     1     1 NA                   NA
2     2     2 NA                   NA
3     3     3 Calculation done      6
4     4     4 Calculation done      8
5     5     5 Calculation done     10
```

Comment: This looks neat, however I cannot run the code after pasting it. It says that ```out``` cannot be found ?

Comment: I am using R 4.1.2 and dplyr 1.0.7. Try upgrading both to the latest versions. If you cannot upgrade, then use another wrapper around the script like this `mutate(local({...}))`. @mikacrem